# BackGroundWorker - fill Datatable and populate anywhere

Tags: mysql, vb.net, multithreading, datatable, backgroundworker

I want to populate differnt forms and GUIs from a Datatable which i fill from a MySQL Database. All this should happen through a backgroundworker. I do know that I can not populate data on another form if it was obtained on another thread (BGW).
Is there a way how I can generically fetch data from the SQL-DB, write it into my Datatable and print it on any form and any GUI that I have in my project?

Where to start reading?

## edit:

So far i do have a user-control which does connect to the DB, retrieve the requested data and passes it in form of a data table to a function. this function populates a datagridview on the main form and also passes the data to other functions and forms in the project. As i understood the backgroundworker tutorials i read till now, it would not be possible to populate/write the data on ANY form in the project. Because each time i want to write the data into a e.g. textbox i need to
**invoke** the data because it was obtained on another thread.
in my case these would be dozens of controls on different forms. and this is where i am stuck. basically im looking for a generic way to **invoke** all data in the **datatable** one time and from there on i can write it to any user-control i wish. is that anyhow possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow drumbun! Although you did describe your problem, it is difficult to help you without knowing what your code looks like. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Put all the necessary logic for interacting with the database in a separate project and compile it as a class library (DLL).  Then add it as a reference to your UI project.  Then each form that needs to access the data can do so through this DLL, even using a background worker if desired.

Comment: @Tim, that way it works only if i bind it as compiled DLL into my project, right? it would not work if i just create a class library inside my project and load "DB-Fetcher-Objects" of it?

Comment: @drumbun - I would make it a DLL for reusability, but you could simply create a class in your UI project and use it in the same manner.

Comment: @Tim, maybe i didnt explain myself good enough in the first posting. i edited it.. maybe u can state ur opinion now :)

Comment: @drumbun - If I read your edit correctly, you want to get the data from the database once, and use it (possibly) in multiple places.  If that understanding is correct, then I'd either store it in a collection object and the controls could read the data from that object, or put it into [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) and retrieve the data from there.

Comment: i already retrieve the data and write it to the controls in a manner that i would not 
like to change. the problem is that when the mysql-request causes a 'large' 
response the GUI gets stuck while it waits for the data. 
i want to put the data-fetching process on another thread to prevent the freezing of the form. 
id also like to stick with datatables because i fill several datagridviews with their data...